# How to find if one of the indexes for an element in a linked list is zero in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linked list. An item may be at several indexes of this list (e.g. index 0, index 3, and index 5). How can I find if one of these indexes is index 0; I need that because I use some formulas to calculate some values, and the formula is different if one position of the item is index 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `get` method on list and the `equals` method on your item

```
list.get(0).equals(myItem);
```

Normally you don't want to use `get(int)` on a `LinkedList` because it's an order n traversal. But index 0 will always be at the front and is a very short traversal. :)

Comment: You are right. Sometimes the answer is much easier than we think ... Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can check the first element is the object you want

```
if (list != null && list.size() > 0 && list.get(0).equals(element))
```

Comment: Actually your answer is the most complete answer, checking every case (if the list is null, checking the size of the list etc.). Due to the way I wrote the piece of code of interest, I do not need these checks I think, but in general that is the right way to do it. I will keep that in mind in the future. Very helpfull answer, thank you. Unfortunatelly I cannot give you points yet, since I am new member and I have small reputation (less than 15 which is required to vote up) ...